# 3D-plot using uneven matrices

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to build 3D-plot using uneven matrices?
For example I have 3 matrices: x, t, u(values in points (x[i][j]; t[i][j]))

```
t = [[0, 0, 0],
[0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03],
[0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06],
...]
x = [[-0.5, -0.25, 0.0],
[-0.5, -0.375, -0.25, -0.1875, -0.0625, 0],
[-0.5, -0.25, -0.125, 0],
...]
```

Now I have an error on third line:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x_matrix, t_matrix, u, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=1)
```

Error: *ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.*

Comment: Can you post more explicitly exactly what arrays you are plotting?  You've *kinda sorta* shown t and x but not in a way that's reproducible, and you haven't shown x_matrix, t_matrix, or u.  Debugging requires knowing exactly what you did, not approximately what you did.

Comment: I solved my problem. Matplotlib cannot draw plot wireframe with uneven matrices. So I set points with scatter and linked it with plot method.